# Cannot select target in SQL Server Schema Compare, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, schema-compare

I'm having an odd problem which I haven't been able to find a solution for. Suddenly I am not able to select a *Target* or *Source* in Schema Compare in VS2017. When I click the Combobox nothing happens. It is still possible to do a Data Compare and SQL Queries.

I've updated SSDT to version 15.5.1 but with no success. VS is version 15.5.2

Comment: It seems to be the same problem as decribed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419310/sql-server-compare-schema-in-visual-studio-2017/48092813?noredirect=1#comment83159979_48092813

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work using the arrow keys.  A workaround, but definitely malfunctioning drop downs.  See also [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27788/sql-schema-compare-datasource-dropdowns-not-workin.html)

Comment: The workaround worked until magically it started working again :\

Comment: I had the same issue. I restarted my visual studio and it worked.

Comment: VS 2019 Enterprise - v.16.4.2. I restarted VS, my laptop multiple time to no avail... workaround, keys, worked... HORRIBLE... (also i updated VS)